# Magento 2 Get category active filters name and id in Category page

Tags: filter, magento2.2.3

For **testing purpose**, I'm writing my code in the following file.

> app/design/frontend/Joemerino/base/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver');
    $layer = $filterableAttributes->get();
    $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($activeFilters);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

But it's empty even if two filters applied.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try the below code its working for me:

Below code will return the filters which are already applied to the category page or seach result page by customer, In magento you can say State

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stateFilter = $objectManager->create('\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State');
$selectedFilters = $stateFilter->getActiveFilters();
foreach($selectedFilters as $filter){
    echo $filter->getName(); // Filter name like Color, Size etc
    echo $filter->getLabel(); // Filter value like Black, Blue, Small, Large etc
}
```

Comment: How to use above script as module?

Comment: Where will output display?

Comment: Create a module with template and add the above to code to your template file. For best practice inject the used class to your block class constructor and use it accordingly.

Comment: Actually i integrated your code into my theme, where can i see the output?

Comment: where did you added the code?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\design\frontend\Zero_theme\My_theme\Magento_Swatches\templates\product\layered\renderer.phtml

Comment: You can check it in your left panel of your product listing page but it will only work if color swatches in your layered navigation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119003/discussion-between-zus-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119003/discussion-between-zus-and-sukumar-gorai

Comment: what about normal attributes, how ti change the condition? my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330123/57334

Comment: For me, i want to get active attributes and display category description CMS block based on that attribute.

Comment: Can i get some code help or structure, i am new to this.