# How to add cms static block to category description programmatically

Tags: magento2.3.4, programmatically, cms-block, category-description

Instead of directly add cms block to category description, how to add programmatically?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? if what i am reading is correct you would need to create a module with a InstallData or a patch file which should allow you to update the descriptions of categories with a single / multiple static blocks if the category IDs are specified.

Comment: Actually i want to change my category description cms block based on layered navigation attributes selection, eg. If customer choose color red my category description set cms static block id : 10, if my customer choose color green my category description set cms block id : 11

Comment: If this is the case you will need to a custom module which gets the current active filters and change the block content using ajax.

Comment: I want to change category description dynamically, by default magebto has option  for adding cms block under category description, i need to set the cms block based on selection of layered navigation atributes, i hope you understand my point, sorry for my english.

Comment: Yes i understand the requirements but you will need to map the cms blocks to the attribute option values and return the content to the page using ajax. if you loaded all the content on initial load this would cause page speed issues.

Comment: For that page issue what is the best practice?

Comment: Best practice would be custom module with mapped attribute values > cms block id and the content being passed via Ajax as this would minimise the overall page loading time.

Comment: Can i get some code help or structure, i am new to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119038/discussion-between-zus-and-dava-gordon).